# Is it legal to use opponent's stones in reversi or othello?

Tags: othello

In Reversi or Othello, it is sometimes possible that you run out of stones but still need to make a move. Sources disagree upon the fact if you can or must use opponent's stones in this case. I watched numerous videos and people disagree so much about this rule. Someone say you can't use opponent's stones at all; others say you can and a few, you must.

I just wonder: Is there a unique official rule concerning this problem? Because if everyone starts playing according to their personal rules, that won't be too good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at a few sources for Othello rules, and they either didn't have any rules that cover this edge case or like [Ultra Board Games](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/othello/game-rules.php) state that you should take discs from your opponent if you run out.

> When a player runs out of discs, but still has opportunities to outflank an opposing disc, then the opponent must give the player a disc to use.

Comment: Maybe they use double sided discs, where one side is black and the other side is white, so there is no "my discs" and "your discs"

Comment: @Cohensius: I've never heard of a Reversi set that doesn't use reversible discs. I struggle to imagine how that would ever be practical to play. You'd have to constantly remove and replace discs every time someone made a move.

Comment: @Cohensius The discs are double sided, but rather than having a single pool that each player takes discs from the rules have them each take 32 as "their" discs (unless their opponent runs out)